# Total Cost in JOptionPane not showing up

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

How do I get the total cost to show up as a joptionpane, and the beverages in it as well. I was asked to simulate a Breakfast ordering system for BeBe’s Best Breakfast. I am to display a JOptionPane to prompt the user for choices of breakfast and a beverage to order. I am then to provide a prompt for the number of these breakfasts to be ordered by the office (from 1 - 5) and use a Scanner object to read in his input. And then output the user’s Bill in a JOptionPane.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Locale;
public class ProjectFourA
{
    private static final float bagel = 2.00f, donut = 1.50f, croissant = 3.00f;
    private static final float latte = 1.50f, coffee = 1.25f, milk = 1.00f, tea = 0.50f;
    private float cost,extracost;
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner breakfast = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberFormat mfmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        int size, choice, num;
        String ch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome to BeBe's Best Breakfast choose a breakfast item." + "\n1 to order Bagel"+"\n2 to order Donut"+"\n3 to order Croissant");
  choice = Integer.parseInt(ch);

  String nm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose one of the following beverages:" + "\n1 for Latte"+"\n2 for Coffee"+"\n3 for Milk"+"\n4 for Tea");
  num = Integer.parseInt(nm);
  float cost=0.0f, extracost=0.0f;
  float price;
  String str="", topstr="";
  if (choice == 1)
  {
     cost = bagel;
     str = "Bagel";
     String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter quantity: 1-5");
     inputStr = breakfast.nextLine();  
  }
     else if (choice == 2)
  {
     cost = donut;
     str = "Donut";
     String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter quantity: 1-5");
     inputStr = breakfast.nextLine();
  }
     else if (choice == 3)
  {
     cost = croissant;
     str = "Croissant";
     String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter quantity: 1-5");
     inputStr = breakfast.nextLine();
  }
     float totCost = extracost + cost;
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,( "Breakfast ordered:" +str +   "\nBeverage ordered: "+topstr + "\nTotal cost: $"+totCost));
  }
 }
```

Comment: I recommend that you try to improve the formatting of your code that you post in here and your code in general. Good formatting including using an indentation style that is uniform and consistent will help others (**us**!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, it will help **you** to better understand your code and thus fix your own bugs. Also it shows that you're willing to put in extra effort to make it easier for the volunteers here to help you, and that effort is **much** appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem looks to be the line `inputStr = breakfast.nextLine();` in each if block. You are not entering any input for this. So it does not execute your showMessageDialog.

Remove `inputStr = breakfast.nextLine();`

```
if (choice == 1) {
            cost = bagel;
            str = "Bagel";
            String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter quantity: 1-5");

        } else if (choice == 2) {
            cost = donut;
            str = "Donut";
            String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter quantity: 1-5");

        } else if (choice == 3) {
            cost = croissant;
            str = "Croissant";
            String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter quantity: 1-5");

        }
        float totCost = extracost + cost;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                ("Breakfast ordered:" + str + "\nBeverage ordered: " + topstr
                        + "\nTotal cost: $" + totCost));
```